# Webservice - how can I drop unwanted requests? (Dropwizard/Spring Boot)

Tags: java, web-services, security, spring-boot, dropwizard

Suppose I am running a REST webservice built in Dropwizard or Spring Boot. It has one or a few resources (paths) configured which provide some services to clients.

Now, ocassionally, there are requests on other paths that are not configured, in other words they are invalid for this service.

I can't tell if these are malicious or simply mistakes. They might just be erronous, but there is always a risk that they are attempts to probe my service for weakpoints.

My desire is to imediately drop such requests so that they take up no resources in my service, while providing absolutely no feedback to the client.

So my questions are:

1. Is this a good idea in the first place?
2. If yes, how can this best be achieved in Dropwizard or Spring Boot?
3. If no, what would be a good approach?

**Edit**:
To clarify the third point, if the idea of simply dropping the request and leave the poor client hanging is *not* a good idea, what other way of handling such requests is advisable instead?

Comment: If the endpoints are not defined for those "invalid" requests then the clients are getting 404 by default correct? To make sure I understand the question, you want the service to skip the logic that checks if an endpoint is defined all-together? Thanks.

Comment: @AndréBarbosa That could be one option. Another way might be to define a wildcard endpoint of some sort (@Path("/{anything}") possibly?) to catch these requests and then drop them somehow. I have yet to find out how to do the latter though.

Comment: You might be able to achieve this using the "@Path("/{path: .*}")" expression on the service but implementing your own logic to determine which paths are invalid might be more "expensive" than letting DW handle the non-defined endpoints.

Comment: Returning a 404 doesn't take much resources. If you're worried about a Denial-of-Service attack, your REST service isn't the right layer to worry about that. Put your service behind something like CloudFlare or implement your own using nginx+fail2ban